# How to achieve this kind of "texture" with Affinity Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer

I would like to know how to reproduce something like this dark rectangle in Affinity Designer:

[image]

I can see it's a rectangle, if I'm not mistaken there's some sort of slight gradient and maybe some noise, but my attempts at reproducing it look nothing like it. I don't care that much about the logo, font or the text at the bottom, I'm really just curious about the overall cover.

Edit: Here's my (vain) attempt:

[image]

- I used a gradient over the rectangle with the colors I picked from top left and bottom right of the original picture;
- I somehow based the color of the font on the original picture, although it's different.

It's really not clear to me if the background is that different from mine or if it's just an effect for the special kind of font they're using plus the logo.

Comment: It’s impossible to tell whether there’s any noise in the dark rectangle in that image due to the artefacting from the very heavy-handed compression. There may be deliberately added noise, or it may just be the artefacting. Other than that, yeah, it just looks like a subtle radial gradient to me. Can you show what your attempts have looked like? We can’t really know what you’re doing wrong without seeing what you’ve done.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I see. I posted what I came up with. I'm a complete beginner, so nothing great..

Comment: I think your gradient is a bit **too** subtle. On my phone here, I have to squint really hard to see it’s not just a flat black. Your blue text is too dark, but the main thing, I think, is that you have no border (which also looks like it’s a gradient?) and drop shadow like in the original. Those both go a long way in adding texture and a sense of depth.